# Changing database SQL connection in Excel file breaks even though the new SQL query works in Access

Tags: sql, ms-access, excel-2010

I have an excel file with a connection to an Access database that refreshes when the excel file is opened (Access 2010 and Excel 2010). It uses a SQL query to populate a table. The query used to work fine when it was this:

```
SELECT U.WkEnd, U.Error, COUNT(U.Error) AS [Count], M.NumOpen
FROM tbl_002_Updates AS u
INNER JOIN 
(SELECT Finish-Weekday(Finish,5)+7 AS WkEnd, COUNT(*) AS NumOpen FROM tbl_001_Master WHERE Status IN ('A', 'M') 
   GROUP BY Finish-Weekday(Finish,5)+7) AS M 
ON M.WkEnd = U.WkEnd
WHERE U.Error IS NOT NULL AND Year(U.WkEnd) = 2020
GROUP BY U.WkEnd, U.Error, M.NumOpen
ORDER BY U.WkEnd;
```

I updated the query to the following:

```
SELECT T.WkEnd, T.Error, T.WkNum, m.NumOpen
FROM 
(
SELECT DISTINCT D.WkEnd As WkEnd, 'DED' As Error, NZ(P.WkNum, 0) As WkNum from tbl_002_Updates AS D LEFT JOIN 
   (SELECT WkEnd, Count(Error) As WkNum FROM tbl_002_Updates WHERE Error = 'DED' GROUP BY WkEnd) AS P 
   ON D.WkEnd = P.WkEnd 
UNION 
SELECT DISTINCT D.WkEnd As WkEnd, 'PCS' As Error, NZ(P.WkNum, 0) As WkNum from tbl_002_Updates AS D LEFT JOIN 
   (SELECT WkEnd, Count(Error) As WkNum FROM tbl_002_Updates WHERE Error = 'PCS' GROUP BY WkEnd) AS P 
   ON D.WkEnd = P.WkEnd 
UNION 
SELECT DISTINCT D.WkEnd As WkEnd, 'Planner' As Error, NZ(P.WkNum, 0) As WkNum from tbl_002_Updates AS D LEFT JOIN 
   (SELECT WkEnd, Count(Error) As WkNum FROM tbl_002_Updates WHERE Error = 'Planner' GROUP BY WkEnd) AS P 
   ON D.WkEnd = P.WkEnd
)  AS T 
INNER JOIN 
(SELECT Finish-Weekday(Finish,5)+7 AS WkEnd, COUNT(*) AS NumOpen FROM tbl_001_Master WHERE Status IN ('A', 'M')
   GROUP BY Finish-Weekday(Finish,5)+7)  AS M 
ON M.WkEnd = T.WkEnd
WHERE Year(T.WkEnd) = 2020
ORDER BY T.WkEnd;
```

The new query works fine in Access. I didn't change the authentication information or anything else, only the Excel connection command text, and now I get the errors "The query did not run, or the database table could not be opened" and then "The following data range failed to refresh".

The only thing I can think of is that there might be certain functions or keywords that work in Access but don't work in Excel connections to Access databases, but I can't find anything about this online. Not sure what else would cause it to fail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's just the nz() function that's breaking it, it works if you replace it with iif(isnull())